# How Last Edge Image Can Be Achieved from Law Masks

Tags: image-processing, edge-detection, texture

as we know thechnique of law edge detection has 25 2d masks that is obtained form 5 different 1d filters. we can use each of those masks on image with convolution but how can we obtain final result? is that achieved from from some kind of fusion or it have to be chosen?

thank you

Comment: I'm not sure what you're talking about. Could you give a reference to the technique you're referring to?

Comment: @marcus https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_texture    searh for Laws Texture Energy Measures

Comment: OK, so it's "Law**s** Texture Energy Measures". The letters do make a difference. Also, I think the article is pretty well-explained and says exactly what you do – can you please be clearer *by editing your question* about what *exactly* you need help with?

Comment: @MarcusMüller   I want to know how edge detection works for it? it has 25 filters and result of each one of them on image has different result. how can right result be achieved from these?

Comment: The source text [9] is pretty explicit: *"a set of nine 5x5 convolution masks is used to compute the energy of texture which is then represented by a nine element vector for each pixel."* it's that 9 element vector that describes the texture. Done - no step after. Section 7.3.4. There's a good reason that Wikipedia encourages people to cite their sources, and that is that interested and skeptic readers can read the original text.

Comment: @MarcusMüller really its not obvious for me. can you give me algorithmic way to use Law? what I can say is: law has 5 different filteres for ripples waves and... masks are build from multiplying these filters. so right now how they work on image? as I understand each of them is a distinct filter. so last output is result if image with which one of them?

Comment: Is your question how to convolve an image with a mask? I really don't understand what your problem is. No, the result is not an image. If your original image was of size $n\times m$, the resulting structure is of shape $n\times m \times 9$.

Comment: @MarcusMüller right now you said the answer. the problem is result of edge detection is an image. after resulting n*m*9 structure, how should I work with it? my real question was what should I do with 9 of n*m structure? as I have coded law texture each one of them was look like an edge image but with different accuracy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the question is, given many images which are result of different Edge Filter applied on the same image, how to actually mark edges.

Well, you basically created 25 tests for each pixel to decide whether or not it is an edge.

You could apply many approaches to decide:

1. Majority Votes - If more than half of the voters decided it is an edge, nark it as an edge.
2. Threshold - If more than $ x $ voters vote for edge the pixel will be declared as an edge.
3. Spatial Model - Instead of per pixel decision, look around it and other voters.
4. Weight of Votes - Don't mark votes as "Yes / No" but give it a scalar. If the sum of all scalars above a threshold value, declare an edge.

As you can see the options are endless.